# model.predict() is not producing the expected labels?

Tags: python, keras, classification

I am doing a simple binary text classification.
The steps go roughly like this:

1. preprocess training data with CountVectorizer()
2. build a keras Sequential() model
3. model.fit(x_train, y_train)
4. model.evaluate(x_val, y_val)
5. model.predict(x_test)

I am stuck on step 5 - when I print the predicted values, I get a numpy array of:

```
 [0.9434484 ]
 [0.3787447 ]
 ...
 [0.87870705]
 [0.7575223 ]
 [0.39714795]]
```

Since I am doing a binary classification, and my labels are 0 and 1, I expected the prediction output to be the same? Now it seems like it predicts the probability between the labels 0 and 1, which is not what I wanted. Do I need to encode the prediction output somehow so that it returns the proper labels or have I done something wrong in the steps before??

Comment: What loss function are you using? That will make a difference. Ideally, it should be `binary_crossentropy` for binary classification.

Comment: @AkankshaAtrey I am indeed already using binary_crossentropy

Comment: The returned values are on scale 0-1 representing the probability of 1 being the label

Comment: @Ruli I understand that. My question was, is there any way that the model directly predicts the labels? Or do I have to process them afterwards as another user suggested with round()?

Comment: @kluster i have provided such answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step 5 `model.predict(x_test)` can be replaced by:

```
model.predict_classes(x_test)
```

to predict classes in sequential model. In case you ever need this in functional model in future, this is the solution:

```
y_prob = model.predict(x_test) 
y_classes = y_prob.argmax(axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use simple statistical interpretation where we will be using 0.5 cutoff. Thus everything above 0.5 will be treated as 1 and below as 0.

```py
import numpy as np

pred =  np.array([[0.9434484 ]
 ,[0.3787447 ]
 ,[0.87870705]
 ,[0.7575223 ]
 ,[0.39714795]])

np.round(pred)
Out[37]: 
array([[1.],
       [0.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [0.]])
```

If results is not a probabilities then sth like :

```py
def sigmoid(x):
  return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))
```

have to be used to scale it to 0-1 scale.